# Detail Page View not Showing Data in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic. I write code for list. List is working perfectly but when click on any list-item it's not showing any data. 
It showing me this error "Cannot GET /pilliondetails/1" how can i solve this?

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
var savedData = {}
function set(data) {
savedData = data;
console.log(savedData);
}
function get() {
return savedData;
}

return {
set: set,
get: get
}
})
```

PillionList Controller:

```
.controller('PillionListCtrl',function($scope,$ionicHistory,myService){
$scope.myGoBack = function() {
$ionicHistory.goBack();
};

$scope.pillions = [];
var promise=myService.get();
$scope.pillions=myService.get();
})
```

PillionDetail Controller:

```
.controller('PillionDetailCtrl',function($scope, $ionicHistory, $stateParams, myService)
{
$scope.myGoBack = function() {
$ionicHistory.goBack();
};
var promise=myService.get($stateParams.requestId);
console.log(promise);
})
```

PillionList.html :Showing list pf Pillions

```
   <ion-list>
   <ion-item data-ng-repeat="pillion in pillions">
    <div class="list list-inset">
    {{pillion.request_departure_date}}-{{pillion.request_departure_time}}
    {{pillion.request_from}}&nbsp;&nbsp;>>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{pillion.request_to}}
    {{pillion.user_first_name}}&nbsp;{{pillion.user_last_name}}
    <a ui-sref="pilliondetails({pillionId:pillion.request_id})" nav-direction="enter">
        <h2>More Details...</h2>
    </a>
    </div>
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
```

my app.js

```
 .state('pillionlist', {
            url: '/pillionlist',
            templateUrl: 'templates/pillionlist.html',
            controller: 'PillionListCtrl'
        })

        .state('pilliondetails', {
            url: '/pillionlist/:pillionId',
            templateUrl: 'templates/pilliondetails.html',
            controller: 'PillionDetailCtrl'
        })
```

Its redirecting to pillionDetail view but not showing data.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i noticed is

```
ui-sref="pilliondetails({pillion.request_id})"
```

it should be key-value pair like this

```
ui-sref="pilliondetails({ your_id : pillion.request_id})"
```

and in stateProvider, the url of details page should contain parameter. for eg.

```
url : '/pilliondetails/:your_id'
```

Comment: i tried your suggetion but showing `ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: Invalid state ref 'pilliondetails({pillionId:pillion.request_id})` this error

Comment: i added my app.js in my question pls refer that & help me

Comment: it works but its not showing details of particular id it carries whole data on detail page. i used console.log() to know what data is available on detail page.

Comment: it should be var promise=myService.get($stateParams.pillionId);
you are passing pillionId.